# Is there a cleaner or more efficient to do this Python assignment?

Tags: python, variable-assignment

Here's the code I have now:

```
lang = window.get_active_document().get_language()
if lang != None:
    lang = lang.get_name()
```

Is there a better way to do that? I'm new to Pythonic and was wondering if there's a more Python way to say "something equals this if x is true, else it equals that."

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do `lang = lang and lang.get_name()` instead of the 'if' statement.

If lang is None it will stay None. If not, it will be set to lang.get_name().

I'm not sure if that syntax makes things much clearer, though.

P.S. Instead of `lang != None` you should use `not lang is None`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give a quick explanation? The syntax doesn't make much logical sense to me, and Googling for 'python and' doesn't get me anywhere.

Comment: Mike, if X is false in the clause "X and Y" then the clause evaluates to false and Y is not evaluated. None evaluates to False, so in "lang and  lang.get_name()" , if lang is None the clause returns false and get_name is never called, otherwise get_name is called. The clause returns the last value evaluated, so the return value of "get_name" comes back.

Comment: @Mike Crittenden, In Python, `and` always returns one of its arguments. If the first argument is true, it knows that the result depends wholly on the second argument's truth or falsehood so it just returns the second argument. If the first argument is false it short-circuits and returns the first argument. Similar things happen for `or`.


As you point out, it isn't all that obvious or clear. In the case of replacing `is not None`, it can also be buggy. Personally, I never use `and` this way.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
lang = lang.get_name() if lang else None
```

Comment: @Sudhir, did you mean "lange" or "lang"?  I'd correct it as a typo, but I'm not sure whether it was intentional or accidental.

Comment: I think it was 'lange' in the original question... I was wondering why too :D

Comment: Yeah, I accidentally put lange at first.

Answer (score 2):

```
try:
    lang = window.get_active_document().get_language().get_name()
except AttributeError:
    lang = None
```

The advantage here is that window itself and all three nested methods become guarded in one statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is fine and clearer most solutions offered so far.  Slightly more pythonic would be:

```
lang = window.get_active_document().get_language()
if lang:
    lang = lang.get_name()
```

or

```
lang = window.get_active_document().get_language()
if lang is not None:
    lang = lang.get_name()
```